# Rails: Two different Ajax features not working together on same button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Made a comment system that shows/hides by a JS file but at the same time this comment system is controlled by the same button that is used as a view counter. Both are run by two different Ajax files but both won't work without the other one not working. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT** the HTML isn't using `@micropost` and using `micropost` because `@micropost` is defined in a different partial. For those who are familiar to Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, I have done this micropost with his code and teachings. I know this is screwing up everything for the ajax which is bringing back a `@micropost` rather than `micropost` but it won't let me not put a `@` in the ajax file so I am lost

**Comment Button HTML**

```
<span class='count-<%= micropost.id%>'>
<a href="/microposts/<%=micropost.id %>/upview" data-remote='true' class='CommentTitle' data-micropost='<%= micropost.id %>'>Comments</a>
</span>
```

**Comment Ajax for changing counter**

```
$("#count-<%=@micropost.id%>").html('<%="#{@micropost.view_count}"%>');
$(".count-<%=@micropost.id%>").html('<a href="/microposts/<%=@micropost.id%>/upview" data-remote="true" class="CommentTitle" data-micropost="<%= @micropost.id %>">Comments</a>');
```

**Comment Button Slide Toggle JS**

```
$(".CommentTitle").click(function(){
var title = this;
var postID = $(this).data('micropost');
$("#CommentContainer-" + postID).slideToggle("slow", function(){ 
$(".CommentTitle", title).html($(this).is(":hidden") ? "Comments" : "Comments");  
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: When the user clicks on the link in the html, they're sending a request to your `upview` action inside your `MicropostsController`.

Inside that controller action method, you can assign an instance variable...

```
@this_micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id]) # assuming you're RESTful, which it looks like
```

then, inside your `upview.js.erb`, you can use that instance variable for whatever you want.

Hope this helps!